# Is there a keyboard shortcut to clear a filter in the left hand navigators in XCode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I can choose the navigator I want using `⌘`+`1`, `⌘`+`2`, etc. and I can jumpt to the filter bar using `opt`+`⌘`+`j`.

Is there a shortcut that can clear the filter that is better than option-command-j, then command-a, followed by a backspace?
[image]

Comment: I was looking for a shortcut to directly jump to the filter box. This helped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Just press the `Esc` key.

```
"Option-Command-J", "Esc"
```

Comment: so simple and obvious, yet genius.

Comment: I was actually looking for an answer to short cut to left side filter box, thanks man!

Comment: In 12.3 "Option-Command-J", "backspace", because it selected the text in the filter automatically.